# AuthLogic + PostgreSQL 8.4: persistence_token defined as a string, then used as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, authlogic

I'm trying to integrate AuthLogic into my rails application, and I followed the example which defines persistence_token as a string :

https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example

However when I run it with PostgreSQL 8.4 on my ubuntu desktop I get the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#index

PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = 21007622...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = 2100762299)  LIMIT 1
```

I tried to change persistence_token to an integer, but then it seemed other parts of AuthLogic did not update it.

I'm sure this must be a common problem but googling around was not very helpful, any ideas how to resolve this?

Ruby version: 1.8.7
Rails version: 2.3.5
AuthLogic version: 2.1.6

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried Authlogic for the first time. I couldn't find a real solution, but restarting the project from scratch fixed it for me.

Comment: we have this problem as well, but only when testing with rspec. The actual application works just fine.

Comment: What version of Ruby? Rails seems to need 1.8.7 or 1.9.2. What version of Rails? 3.0.3 seems to be the current version. What version of AuthLogic? 2.1.6 seems to be current. PostgreSQL is on version 9.0.2, but I doubt that's at the root of your problem.

Comment: @Catcall: I added these version numbers into the original question

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem because the rows in your table have a 'persistence_token' value of nil.  Setting the column to a value will cause this error to go away.  I suspect it has something to do with the way rails inspects the table columns and its interaction with authlogic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code that declares persistence_token?

I'd try type casts and conversions first. On the SQL side, all these will work.

```
 WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = cast(2100762299 as varchar))
 WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = 2100762299::text)
 WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = text(2100762299))
 WHERE ("users"."persistence_token" = 2100762299 || '')
```

That last one is an implicit type coercion. It forces PostgreSQL to treat the number as a string by concatenating it to an empty string.

But you might have to change the data type at run time in Ruby.

```
yournumber.to_s
```